# Class C (/24) networks in a /21 network

Tags: networking, subnet

How many equivalent Class C (/24) networks are there in a /21 network? How do we calculate it? I have checked different websites but without success.

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Please let them rest in peace. See [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) and the excellent answer on [networkengineering.se] for how to do this. Hint: IP addresses are binary numbers, and you need to do this in binary, then it becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the difference between prefix lengths is your number:

```
2^(24 - 21) = 8
```